# Ride4Dapps: TypeError Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in invokeScript

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm trying to execute wallet.ride example and I've got some issue with this:

broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"deposit",args:[]}, payment: [{amount: 300000000, asset:null }]}))

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How to fix that?

```scala
# In this example multiple accounts can deposit their funds and safely take them back, no one can interfere with this.
# An inner state is maintained as mapping `address=>waves`.

# You can try this contract by following commands in the IDE (ide.wavesplatform.com)
# Run commands as listed below
# From account #0:
#      broadcast(transfer({recipient:address(env.accounts[1]), amount: 1000000000}))
#      broadcast(transfer({recipient:address(env.accounts[2]), amount: 1000000000}))
# From account #1:
#      deploy()
# From account #2:
#      broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"deposit",args:[]}, payment: [{amount: 300000000, asset:null }]}))
#      # observe state and balance of account(1)
#      broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"deposit",args:[]}, payment: [{amount: 200000000, asset:null }]}))
#      # observe state and balance of account(1)
#      broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"withdraw",args:[{type:"integer", value: 600000000}]}, payment: []}))
#      # observe error, nothing changed
#      broadcast(invokeScript({contractAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"withdraw",args:[{type:"integer", value: 400000000}]}, payment: []}))
#      # observe state and balance of account(1)


{-# STDLIB_VERSION 3 #-}
{-# CONTENT_TYPE DAPP #-}
{-# SCRIPT_TYPE ACCOUNT #-}

@Callable(i)
func deposit() = {
   let pmt = extract(i.payment)
   if (isDefined(pmt.assetId)) then throw("can hodl waves only at the moment")
   else {
        let currentKey = toBase58String(i.caller.bytes)
        let currentAmount = match getInteger(this, currentKey) {
            case a:Int => a
            case _ => 0
        }
        let newAmount = currentAmount + pmt.amount
        WriteSet([DataEntry(currentKey, newAmount)])
   }
}

@Callable(i)
func withdraw(amount: Int) = {
        let currentKey = toBase58String(i.caller.bytes)
        let currentAmount = match getInteger(this, currentKey) {
            case a:Int => a
            case _ => 0
        }
        let newAmount = currentAmount - amount
     if (amount < 0)
            then throw("Can't withdraw negative amount")
    else if (newAmount < 0)
            then throw("Not enough balance")
            else ScriptResult(
                    WriteSet([DataEntry(currentKey, newAmount)]),
                    TransferSet([ScriptTransfer(i.caller, amount, unit)])
                )
    }


@Verifier(tx)
func verify() = {
    true
}
```

Comment: I'm using ide.wavesplatform.com, so it seems like env.SEED sometimes can be "undefined". To prevent from any other "env" glitches I'll try to repeat that locally using node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! 
look at: **fee** = 100000000 and **dappAddress** instead **contractAddress**

```scala
# You can try this contract by following commands in the IDE (ide.wavesplatform.com)
# Run commands as listed below
# From account #0:
#      broadcast(transfer({recipient:address(env.accounts[1]), amount: 100000000, fee: 100000000}))
#      broadcast(transfer({recipient:address(env.accounts[2]), amount: 100000000, fee: 100000000}))
# From account #1:
#      deploy()
# From account #2:
#      broadcast(invokeScript({dappAddress: address(env.accounts[1]), call:{function:"deposit",args:[]}, payment: [{amount: 300000000, asset:null }]}))
#      # observe state and balance of account(1)
```